# apt-get loop for ppa's

Tags: apt, ppa

I recently wanted to install e17 on ubuntu 12.04. I first tried to use the ppa ~ hannes-janetzek / enlightenment-svn and it did not work for me, because it did not all packages (econnman), I kept searching and found efl /trunk if it contains all packages. By switching the ppa, I uninstall e17 and tried, after, reinstalling, but while install the new package they conflicted with some packages that were not deleted, particularly libefl libefl-bin, but now does not allow me to delete them until repair the last package.

In other words, I can't repare the new package, because I need to delete the old packages, and I can't remove the old packages, because I need repair the new package

I need to delete "libefl" and "libefl-bin" without apply `apt-get -f install`, and after this, use `apt-get -f install`

Help me please

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `ppa-purge` program to remove PPAs. I think you'll have to first add the PPAs back, do an `apt-get update`. Reinstall any packages you removed from the PPA. Use `dpkg` if necessary. See if packages are still in conflict. If not, install `ppa-purge` and use it to remove the PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge <ppa-name>
```

where the PPA name is the same as that which you gave to `add-apt-repository`. This will downgrade all affected packages to versions available without the PPA. You can do so manually, but it's too much of a pain.

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove "libefl" and "libefl-bin" without using `apt-get` I used:

`sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libefl-bin`

after remove one by one with this command, I can use:

`apt-get -f install`